# gensim : KeyError: "word 'sso' not in vocabulary"

Tags: python, nlp

I am using Google pretrained word embeddings(word2vec) to train my model. while using getting an error as below :

```
KeyError: "word 'sso' not in vocabulary"
```

i am trying this below code:

```
import gensim 
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('D:/NLP  JIRA/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True) 
print(model)
words = list(model.wv.vocab)
print(words)
print(model[words])
for words in op:
        print(words)
        obj = model[words]
        print(obj)
```

input i am passing as

```
op = [['observations', 'sso', 'clienttool', 'testing'], ['logouri', 'column', 'clients', 'table', 'accepting', 'values', 'null']]
```